# Replace all elements in vector with its ordinal number

Tags: r

data frame:

```
#    V1    V2
1    abc   23
2    bcd   43
3    cde   54
4    def   10
```

How to replace V1 with its ordinal number?

```
#    V1    V2
1    1     23
2    2     43
3    3     54
4    4     10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
# Original
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("abc", "bcd", "cde", "def"), V2 = c(23L, 
43L, 54L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
dat
  V1 V2
1 abc 23
2 bcd 43
3 cde 54
4 def 10

# Change V1 with numbers
dat$V1 <- 1:nrow(dat)
  V1 V2
1  1 23
2  2 43
3  3 54
4  4 10
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `row_number()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(V1 = row_number())
```

```
  V1 V2
1  1 23
2  2 43
3  3 54
4  4 10
```

Comment: It's good but I need to do it without library :(

Comment: Then take Abdur Rohmans answer. He provided already a base R solution with `dat$V1 <- 1:nrow(dat)`!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, V1 := .I]
```